# Obtain a value but only when the latest (datetime) of all rows containing that value does not equal x

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Example:

```
PK  Date      Status  Serial
----------------------------
1   11012015  1       8888
2   11032015  8       8888
3   12012015  1       8888
4   11032015  1       9999
5   11152015  1       9999
6   12012015  8       9999
```

I am trying to get all values for serial where the last status per the date is  a 1 but if the the last status was an 8 then I need to exclude these serial numbers.

So with the above example 8888 would show up because the last status was 1

while 9999 would be filtered because the last status it had was an 8.

Comment: which sql statement do you use so far ?

Comment: Are records guaranteed to be in chronological order if ordered by the `PK` field? If not, are you guaranteed only a maximum of one record per `Date` - `Serial` combination?

Comment: Did you misspeak? You said `is not a 1` but that's the exact one you want to return.

Comment: The records are not guaranteed to be in chronological order

Comment: rabbit, you are correct, i posed a heads i win tales you lose scenario, i edited the question for accuracy.

Comment: LDMJoe,  affirmative guaranteed only one  date + serial combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets the most recent date by serial, then joins back onto the main table (which I refer to as `YourTable` here because you didn't provide an actual name) to get the rest of the data.  Your filtering happens in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT
    YourTable.PK, 
    YourTable.[Date],
    YourTable.[Status],
    YourTable.Serial
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        Serial, 
        MAX([Date]) AS [MaxDate]
    FROM
        YourTable
    GROUP BY
        Serial
    ) DerivedMaxDateBySerial
    LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTable ON DerivedMaxDateBySerial.Serial = YourTable.Serial AND DerivedMaxDateBySerial.[MaxDate] = YourTable.[Date]
WHERE
    YourTable.[Status] != 8
```

Comment: I've tested and this is returning the results i expect, thank you!

Comment: @Wolfgang Great!  Please upvote and accept then!  I'm trying to get to my 1k rep!  :)

Comment: I accepted and did upvote but i am too noob for it to show up ;)  thanks again!